# SQLite callback after delete

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to make a delete function with confirmation that something was deleted. With current code rows variable comes back empty if the row is not found or it was deleted.

```
app.delete('/api/devices/:id', (req, res) => {
    db.all('delete from devices where id = ' + req.params.id, (err, rows) => 
{
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err)
        }
        else {
            return res.status(204).send()
        }
    })
})
```

In case if it's not found, I want to return 404, in case it was actually deleted, I want to return 204. How do I tell them apart?

I know I can make a select query prior to deleting it, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/delete/)

> In case the `DELETE` statement executed successfully, the `this` object of
>   the callback function will contain the changes property that stores
>   the number of rows deleted.

You should consider using the `run` method, not the `all` method for the DELETE query, since you are not expecting any results.

Excerpts from the [api doc](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback)

> Runs the SQL query with the specified parameters and calls the
>   callback afterwards. It does not retrieve any result data.

...

> If execution was successful, the this object will contain two
>   properties named lastID and changes which contain the value of the
>   last inserted row ID and the number of rows affected by this query
>   respectively. Note that lastID only contains valid information when
>   the query was a successfully completed INSERT statement and changes
>   only contains valid information when the query was a successfully
>   completed UPDATE or DELETE statement. In all other cases, the content
>   of these properties is inaccurate and should not be used. The .run()
>   function is the only query method that sets these two values; all
>   other query methods such as .all() or .get() don't retrieve these
>   values.

Comment: for this to work you have to have a class, right? Because if I add this.changes inside the callback function it's undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201404/this-changes-sqlite-returns-undefined this is the question about the same issue it is unanswered. I found some information that it can be because of arrow functions, but even with a regular function it's undefined for me. So this is not really helpful.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked important bit: lastID is set by the `run` function, not the `all`. Info and explanation added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else hits this page in search for `sqlite3 this.lastID` and `sqlite this.changes` return `undefined` after a delete query;

The code snippet above should read:

```
app.delete('/api/devices/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.run('delete from devices where id = ?', req.params.id, function(err) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err)
    return res.status(204).send(this.lastID) // or this.changes
  })
})
```

These were the things missing from the OP snippet:

1. we need to execute a `run` command on the database instance, not `all` which is by the way memory inefficient...
2. the sqlite query was missing the question mark for the parametized variable (the id)
3. the `this` context is lost if we use arrow functions
4. the `run` method callback has only one parameter, the error object